# show image in dompdf , codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, dompdf

When I view the page I can see an error saying "Image not found" which   links to the supposedly not found image which displays fine when you click on it.

I've tried adding a .png extension to the page generating the image but that doesn't make any difference. I've also saved the generated image to the server and linked to that instead and it works fine.

The only method I can think of to solve this is to save the image on the server and then link to that. Ideally, I don't want to do this so I was wondering if anybody had come across this before or if anyone can think of a fix for it.
The version of dompdf I'm using is 0.6.0 beta 3 and I'm using it with CodeIgniter.

Please see below code, I'm trying to show image in my CodeIgniter view page with dompdf, but I am not able to show it.

```
<?php require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
require_once'dompdf/autoload.inc.php' $dompdf = new Dompdf\Dompdf();
$html =  $this->load->view ('visitor_data',[],true);
$dompdf-> load_html ($html);

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();
// Get the generated PDF file contents

$pdf = $dompdf->output();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream("visitor-data",array("Attachment"=>0));    ?>
```

Below is the view:

```
<?php echo "<img src='base_url()/upload/$row[image]'/> " ;?>
```

Comment: Dompdf 0.6.0 beta 3? Have you tried upgrading? Also, are you really loading your view like that (not passing any data)?

Comment: actually i am fetching  data from view file

Comment: Can you post a sample of the image path? Does dompdf have sufficient permissions to the temp directory? Are the required ibraries installed? Can you clarify the following: "I've tried adding a .png extension to the page generating the image"?